# jQuery in Pop up window in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, popup

I am implementing a web application using .net MVC4. I use kendo UI widgets in my app which uses jQuery for creating widgets. In a page there are 3 pop up kendo windows and each has some kendo widgets on, so uses jQuery. I included jQuery on popups and layout page. both jQueries are same versions. As I click on a button which opens the popup firefox inspect element gives me this error
*"TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined"*
which refers to `$("#addRankWindow").data("kendoWindow").center().open();`
I use `jQuery.noConflict();` and jQuery instead of $ on popups
Everything works fine with Google Chrome and IE, another points is that sometimes it works in firefox without any problem!!
Does anyone have any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you dont have kendo javascript loaded when you are making this call. ( if you include more details, code etc, it might be easier to figure out whats going on in your case)

1. You want to make sure that you are calling kendo methods on document ready.
2. Make sure that all scripts are loaded in correct order

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
This is the order of loading scripts

Comment: The order seems to look fine. Would you be able to share full page code?